# R: Adjust Range to start at 0, Adjust dataframe values accordingly

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe containing two columns with numerical values.  I want to adjust the range of the values while maintaining the relative distance between the numerical values.  The example explains this better.

Is there a standard function that accomplishes this?

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  Start = c(175000, 183597, 185317, 188307, 191390),
  Stop = c(182548, 184724, 187841, 188599, 192650)
)

Range_Start <- df$Start[df$Name=="C"] - 10000
Range_Stop <- df$Stop[df$Name=="C"] + 10000

Range_Start2 <- 1
Range_Stop2 <- length(Range_Start:Range_Stop)

df2 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Start2 = Start - Range_Start) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Stop2 = Stop - Range_Start)
```

Desired Values:

```
> df2$Start2
[1]  -317  8280 10000 12990 16073

> df2$Stop2
[1]  7231  9407 12524 13282 17333
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to go `rowwise`:

```r
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Start = c(181391, 183597, 185317, 188307, 191390), Stop = c(182548, 184724, 187841, 188599, 192650)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Start = c(181391, 183597, 185317, 188307, 191390), Stop = c(182548, 184724, 187841, 188599, 192650), Start2 = c(6074, 8280, 10000, 12990, 16073), Stop2 = c(7231, 9407, 12524, 13282, 17333)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")))

out <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Start2 = Start - Start[Name == "C"] + 10000,
    Stop2 = Start2 + (Stop - Start)
  )
out
#   Name  Start   Stop Start2 Stop2
# 1    A 181391 182548   6074  7231
# 2    B 183597 184724   8280  9407
# 3    C 185317 187841  10000 12524
# 4    D 188307 188599  12990 13282
# 5    E 191390 192650  16073 17333

all.equal(out, df2, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Rerun with updated data:

```r
df <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Start = c(175000, 183597, 185317, 188307, 191390), Stop = c(182548, 184724, 187841, 188599, 192650)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
df2 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Start = c(175000, 183597, 185317, 188307, 191390), Stop = c(182548, 184724, 187841, 188599, 192650), Start2 = c(-317, 8280, 10000, 12990, 16073), Stop2 = c(7231, 9407, 12524, 13282, 17333)), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), groups = structure(list(.rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame")))

out <- df %>%
  mutate(
    Start2 = Start - Start[Name == "C"] + 10000,
    Stop2 = Start2 + (Stop - Start)
  )
out
#   Name  Start   Stop Start2 Stop2
# 1    A 175000 182548   -317  7231
# 2    B 183597 184724   8280  9407
# 3    C 185317 187841  10000 12524
# 4    D 188307 188599  12990 13282
# 5    E 191390 192650  16073 17333
all.equal(out, df2, check.attributes = FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: I adjusted my example to capture an extra criteria.  Sometimes the value of Start2 is negative, and this creates problems when attempting to use it to calculate Stop2.

Comment: My code still produces your `df2` unchanged. Can you help me to understand what is wrong about its return? @JVGen

Comment: Welp, it does appear to work properly on both of my data sets.  I don't know what my sample data is missing, but for some reason it won't work on my actual data.  I have a way that is working with dplyr, but was hoping there would be a function used for adjusting values across a range.  I'll accept your answer because it is indeed working for the sample dataset.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To perform the same operation on mutiple columns (in this case subtracting a fixed amount), we can use `across` inside `mutate`

```r
mutate(df, across(2:3, ~ .x - (Start[Name == "C"] - 1e4), .names = "{.col}2"))
#   Name  Start   Stop Start2 Stop2
# 1    A 181391 182548   6074  7231
# 2    B 183597 184724   8280  9407
# 3    C 185317 187841  10000 12524
# 4    D 188307 188599  12990 13282
# 5    E 191390 192650  16073 17333
```